# Access Angular2 Material sidenav in component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to have access to the sidenav defined in *.component.html so I can dynamically control its mode (over | push | side) based properties such as screen width.

How do I access the md-sidenav below

```
<div class='layout-header'>
  <md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav mode="side" #sidenav>
      <md-nav-list>
        <md-list-item>Blah</md-list-item>
      </md-nav-list>
   </md-sidenav>
   ...
</div>
```

from its component defined in *.component.ts?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'layout-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
  directives: [
    MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES,
    MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES,
    MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,
    MdToolbar,
    MdButton,
    MdInput,
    MdCheckbox,
    MdRadioGroup,
    MdRadioButton,
    MdIcon
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

I'm currently

Answer (score 0):

You could try attribute binding:

```html
<md-sidenav [attr.mode]="sidenavMode" #sidenav>
```

And in your component you have a member variable you can set:

```js
export class HeaderComponent {
    sidenavMode: string = 'side';
}
```

Comment: Did it work? Curious... pretty cool to give the user control over this

Comment: Who knows ... Sometimes people are not the most thankful ...however it should work like that :D

Comment: Yeah.. anyway, I couldn't get it to work, so I had to resolve to the solution I posted above

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to bind the component property like this:

```html
<md-sidenav [mode]="{{sidenavMode}}" #sidenav>
```

Comment: If you bind to an attribute with `[attribute]`, you don't need to interpolate the variable with `{{}}`.

Comment: However, that did not work for me - have you actually tried it yourself?